# How do you make Swift wait for SKAction to be executed?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I have the following Swift code, however, when I run it in Xcode Simulator, it skips straight to "I don't believe we have met before". How do I make Swift wait for "Welcome" to be executed first?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Get label node from scene and store it for use later

    let animateList = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1.0), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0), SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)])

    let startScreen = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica Neue UltraLight")
    startScreen.text = "Welcome"
    startScreen.fontSize = 100.0
    startScreen.fontColor = SKColor.white
    startScreen.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    self.addChild(startScreen)
    startScreen.alpha = 0.0

    startScreen.run(animateList)

    startScreen.text = "I don't belive we have met before"

    startScreen.run(animateList)



    }


}
```

Comment: Don't listen to J. Doe.  You should avoid using Timer when you develop a game with SpriteKit.  Just use SKAction.wait with the SKAction.run completion block.

Comment: Why are you running your animation list twice?

Comment: ahh I thiink I understand what is going on,  you think by changing the text is part of your sequence of actions,  you want to throw that  `startScreen.text = "I don't belive we have met before"` into your sequence using an action block and running your list once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `startScreen.run()`, call `startScreen.run(_:completion)` and do the things you want to do after the `SKAction`s have run inside the completion handler. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483103-run).

```
startScreen.run(animateList, completion: {
    self.startScreen.text = "I don't belive we have met before"
    self.startScreen.run(animateList)
})
```

Comment: EIther this or appending the block to the end of the sequence.  Unfortunately you can't use have both a key and a completion block when running an action (No idea why somebody at Apple did not think of adding this) so you may need to use the append to the end of sequence tactic when you need to assign a key to an action.

Comment: what if you have an array of strings?  how would you loop this?

Comment: Inside completion block, I think it should be self.startScreen.text = "I don't belive we have met before" and also self.startScreen.run(animateList).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a timer which will wait for what you want to execute like this:

```
 _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { _ in
   // do whatever you want after 1 second.
    }
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing this,  if you pause the scene, your timer is going to fire causing problems.

Comment: Moreover, if you change the duration of any of your `SKAction`s, you need to manually change the time in your `Timer` as well, which can easily cause issues. It is better to use the version of `run` that takes a completion handler.